# Rails routing error with get "/locations/around/-17.28794,16.9"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I was trying to replicate a [google maps url](https://www.google.com/maps/@-1.28345,16.12,14z) within my application by including the latitude/longitude of a location within the slug of the url.

I have the following in my routes.rb file:

```
 resources :locations, only: [:create, :show] do
    collection do
      get 'around/:current_location', to:'locations#around'
    end
  end
```

If I try to call that route via the url `get "/locations/around/@-1.28345,16` then this is successfully actioned, however if I call with `get "/locations/around/@-1.28345,16.12` then a routing error is returned.

I'd appreciate some advice as to why the second case is an issue please.

Comment: The first case also will not work as the parameters in the controller are thus: `<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"locations", "action"=>"around", "current_location"=>"@-1", "format"=>"28345,16"} permitted: false>` so would like to understand some alternative approaches too.

Answer (score 0):

There is `format: false` option that ignores matching the format (basically everything after first dot). This feature changes across Rails versions, so you need to experiment. Here are two methods to define it:

```
get 'around/:current_location', to:'locations#around', format: false
```

another:

```
scope format: false do
  get 'around/:current_location', to:'locations#around'
end
```

Comment: Thanks Michal, that didn't actually solve, but led me to this section of Rails routing guide: `By default the :id parameter doesn’t accept dots – this is because the dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a dot within an :id add a constraint which overrides this – for example :id => /[^\/]+/ allows anything except a slash.`

Comment: Therefore changing the route to ` get 'around/:current_location', to:'locations#around', constraints: {current_location:  /[^\/]+/ }` has solved the issue. This is in Rails 6.0.1.